# concentrate and accumulate

Tags: differences

At
http://loe.org/shows/shows.html?programID=03-P13-00018

I saw

> For example, samples of seawater will be filtered and concentrated.

I wonder the difference between "concentrate" and "accumulate".
Can I use "accumulated" at the above sentence?

Or, when it comes to "solution" (including water), is it appropriate to use "concentrated"?

Comment: Rain water might "accumulate" in a bucket while it's raining.  Only when the sun comes out and causes the water to evaporate is it "concentrated".

Comment: concentrate: "to make (something, such as a liquid) stronger by removing water".  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concentrate)  Next step: you look up accumulate.  If you still have a question, come back and ask the new question.  I'm not trying to be snarky.

Comment: Have you looked the words up in a dictionary?  If not, please do so before asking here.  If you have, then please explain what you do not understand about the dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are not the same: [accumulation](http://www.ask.com/science/accumulation-water-cycle-c2db75c630999244) refers to the simple process of gathering but [concentrate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/concentrate) refers to the result of having a purer liquid